Very bad update from 22.04.5 to 24.04.1
This update from Ubuntu 22.04 Ubuntu to 24.04 was a very bad idea!
Interruption during the installation with this message:

"Installation interrupted due to troubles with the Internet connection. I reinstall the previous files"

Previous installation in 5 seconds! And unable to get the control of my computer. Only the grub screen. I tried previous Linux version with the same results.
One of my coder colleagues regains the access by modifying a Linux file (no details provided).
Now I'm in trouble with:

Settings: no access to the "Ubuntu Desktop" settings in the Settings app (I use the Windows key for Applications access).

Oops, something went wrong. Please report a bug in Launchpad.

The same for printers

All windows, only the closing icon (see the above screenshot)

With the administrator account, unable to access to ".thunderbird" repository and all this repository.
...



I got the same error message and was unable to use the Settings app. This turned out to be because of a problem with the proprietary driver for my Nvidia graphics. Does your computer have Nvidia graphics?

This question is similar to: How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which is missing necessary software?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you, that was the solution :)

@jrd10 Then you can mark your question as a duplicate of that one. It may help future users.
